# Flex to have columns of equal width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class='container'> 
    <div class='column'><img></div>
    <div class='column'>text</div>
    <div class='column'>some more text</div>
</div>

.container {display: flex}
.container .column {flex-grow: 1}
```

I noticed that, all the columns are of the same width

**but**

If any of the columns have, say, an image width is wider than the column, the columns grows wider.

Is there a way, I can restrict a column from getting wider without enforcing a width (via CSS or JS) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what the issue is but a max-width on the image plus `flex:1` on the columns seems to work.

[**W3C Flexbox spec**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#propdef-flex)

> By default, flex items won’t shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element). To change this, set the min-width or min-height property. (See §4.5 Implied Minimum Size of Flex Items.)
>
> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the flex shorthand rather than with flex-grow directly, as the shorthand correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate common uses.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 240px;
}
.container .column {
  flex: 1;
  min-width:0; /* Firefox fix */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.column img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='column'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-200-200-2.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class='column'>text</div>
  <div class='column'>some more text</div>
</div>
```

EDIT - [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/o6agcb9r/1/) for re FF fix

Comment: Ah yes ! Thanks a lot :) Hmmmm. I was using "flex-grow" instead of "flex". Although any idea why that works ? As "flex" is a shorthand for "flex-grow, flex-shrink flex-basis". Could it be because shrink and grow have the same value ?